# Fullcalendar and jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, fullcalendar

Good evening everyone!

I need to show the FullCalendar events of my agenda.
I have a list of events in my database and my method returns database data via json (DAO jsp). I'm using dataSet and End date because Java does not support the use of the attributes of reserved words.

my json returns this:

```
[{"id": 3,"title": "Alexandre Garcia","dataStart": "05/09/2016 20:00","dataEnd": "05/09/2016 21:00"}]
```

my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                timezone: "local",
                ignoreTimezone: false,
                editable: false,
                selectable: true,
                minTime: "07:00:00",
                maxTime: "17:00:00",
                slotDuration: "00:60:00",
                allDay: false,
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'app.json',
                        type: "GET",
                        datatype: 'json',
                        success: function (doc) {
                            var events = [];
                            if (doc != undefined && doc.length > 0) {
                                doc.forEach(function (entry) {
                                    events.push({
                                        title: entry.title,
                                        start: entry.dataStart,
                                        end: entry.dataEnd
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                            callback(events);
                        }, error: function (err) {
                            alert('Error in fetching data');
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    alert(calEvent.title);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but my calendar is always empty, could help me?

Comment: Have you checked, that the AJAX call is successfully executed? Add e.g. `alert("AJAX result: " + doc);` before the `var events = [];` line.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek the message says:

AJAX result: [object Object]

Comment: Solved the problem. The problem was in my url.